# How to clear old update installation files?

Tags: boot, updates, uninstall, disk-usage, delete

I recently got a warning, that I only have 5.8MB free space in my `/boot` directory. This information came with the option to 'examine or ignore it'. I examined the file and couldn't do anything, so I decided to close it.

After receiving a notification that an update was available, I clicked upgrade but it said that I didn't have space in that `/boot` directory, so I looked up hundreds of websites, but couldn't find a solution.

After clicking on something by mistake on the update screen, it gave me a code to paste in terminal to clear my old updates. I closed it after copying, but it didn't paste and I could never find that code again) I've downloaded Synaptic Package Manager and it didn't help, but i really need that code.

Please help - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called Ubuntu Tweak [1,2].  It allows you to clear those files.  The "janitor" function is the one you need.

A note, even though it says that it only have the download for 11.04, you can still download it for the later versions of Ubuntu.  It still works.  You can also get the PPA for updates.

Select "Apt Cache" "Old Kernel" "Package Configs" and "Uneeded Packages to clean these for free space.  "Old Kernel" one clears the boot since these sit in that partition.  You can also select the others to gain more space.

[1]http://ubuntu-tweak.com/

[2]https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak

Comment: Are you sure I can download this for 12.04. It says for 11.00 and under next to the download button. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, you can.  It even works for the 13.04.  Thank you for that question, I have added a note about that.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I've downloaded the app and opened the janitor tab. But there are four boxes that I can check "Apt Cache" "Old Kernel" "Package Configs" and "Uneeded Packages". I'm not sure which one to check. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's the boot partition, than Old kernel is what you should pick.  But cleaning all of those will save you move disk space.  Thanks again, and I have edited my answer again.

Comment: Did you get it working?